# Star Schema Data Mart

Tags: star-schema, datamart

Please I'm struggling with the conception this is the Relational diagram of my database:
[image]

so production order has only one machine, and it has its start and end date and quantity to produce. the step has the production each day for a specific order.
what I did is
I create a Dimension called production order that has (Start date, end date, quantity, and id)
-dimension machine
-dimension date   to design  production date
-dimension etat (yes or no) yes if the production is ended (today's date > enddate)
-dimension failed (yes or no) if we produced all the quantity before end date
-fact is stepProduction has id_machine and id_ordreprod and id_date and the quantity.

**But someone told me I should relate my fact 3time with the date dimension so I shouldn't put the start date and end date dimension.**

so please could someone tell me what I did is right !!
Thank you

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure what you're trying to design but that's nothing like a star schema design. Please can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: that's a Relational diagram I am trying to make a star schema based on that, I wrote the different dimension and fact table

Comment: As a star schema is designed based on your analytical requirements, not on the structure of a source system - so that diagram is not much help. A diagram of your star schema would be more helpful as the way you have described your tables is not easy to follow. You've mentioned a number of dimensions not related to your fact, not sure why? If dates are attributes of a fact then they should be modelled as FKs on the fact to date dimension. To comment on whether a technically correct star schema is correct from a business perspective we would need to know your business requirements.